# Function as a Parameter Does not Retain Variable Value

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
fun Controller.doSomething(request: Request): ControllerTask {
    val envelope = request.toEnvelope()
    return ControllerTask() { acceptInvitation(envelope) }
}
```

I add an extension method to a class called `Controller`. This all works very well, but there is a very strange thing happening, when I call `doSomething()`.

`doSomething()` returns a `ControllerTask` which can at a later point in time be executed (using `execute())`.

In `execute()`, the method that was passed to the `ControllerTask` constructor is executed. However, the variable `envelope` seems to not be holding the same value that it was holding when the `ControllerTask` was created in the beginning.

**Am I missing something here? Is my `envelope` variable somehow unassigned, reassigned, or garbage collected?**

The `ControllerTask`'s `execute()` method:

```
class ControllerTask(
    private val task: suspend () -> Response
) : CoroutineScope {

    fun execute() {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = task()
        }
    }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Job() + Dispatchers.Default
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with coroutines, but do you use `Dispatchers.IO` as well as `Dispatchers.Default` on purpose (even though I do not think your problem relates to this).

Comment: Is the `Envelope` object (or whatever `toEnvelope()` returns) mutable?  Could its state have changed, so that even through `envelope` still holds the same reference, the object referred to has different properties?